# What domain name should I use for my extension's fully qualified name?

Tags: extension, civix

I'm getting started with creating extensions and I see that each extension needs a "full name" or "fully qualified name" or "key", which often serves as the name of the git repository too. I see that the domain names used in these fully qualified names are either (1) `civicrm.org` or (2) the domain name of the development shop creating the extension.

I'm not currently part of a development shop, but I'd like to create an extension which I can share with others later on. How should I pick a domain name to use within my extension's fully qualified name?

Comment: But seriously, you can just call it org.civicrm.myextension

Answer (score 1):

You can pick anything you want as the domain name. I sense that these answers could get hilarious. Some suggestions from me (others please add your own):

- [lolcats.com](http://lolcats.com)
- [shouldiblamecaching.com](http://shouldiblamecaching.com)
- [dotcom.com](http://dotcom.com)
- [3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592.com](http://3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592.com)
- [thelongestdomainnameintheworldandthensomeandthensomemoreandmore.com](http://thelongestdomainnameintheworldandthensomeandthensomemoreandmore.com)

But of those, lolcats.com says "extension developer" to me the most:

[image]

Comment: RFC2606: `org.example`